# Selenuim. Получение типа селектора элемента типа By

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Имеется метод:

```
private IWebElement Find(By selector)
{
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Timeout));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(selector));
    return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(selector));
}
```

Вызов метода:
Find(By.Id("id"));

Как в методе Find получить конкретный тип переменной selector.
Под конкретным типом подразумевается одно из значений:

- LinkText
- CssSelector
- Id
- Name
- XPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не айс, но пришлось сделать так

```
var description = selector.ToString();
if (description.Contains("By.LinkText")) 
...
```